# Removing a require_once

Tags: php

I'm working on an application that has a large number of require_once's, and I have removed an unnecessary function call that may have been the only reason for the require. As there is currently a bit of a lattice of require's, is there any reliable way of confirming that the require_once is needed (without manually trying to unwind it)?

I don't believe that our unit tests or behat tests have enough coverage to "remove it and see what breaks"

Comment: the only tool that i know to do this is between the ears

Comment: That was my thoughts as well. As this is a big complex application, I'm not entirely sure if the thing between my ears is good enough ;)